# xpath get the text from multi lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have this html

```
<td width="70%">REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai – U.A.E

RERA ID: 12087

Specialist Licensed Property Brokers &amp; Consultants
Residential / Commercial – Buying, Selling, R <a href="http://www.justproperty.com/company_view/index/3963">...Read more...</a></td>
```

I want to get all the text inside the `td`

#### what i have tried?

```
normalize-space(td/text())
```

but I got only last line.

what should I do to get all the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `u"".join(selector.xpath('.//td//text()').extract())` or `u"".join(selector.css('td ::text').extract())`

I almost forgot the most simple way, if you want every text content of a specific node, you can use `normalize-space()` on it directly:

```
paul@wheezy:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [2]: selector = Selector(text="""<td width="70%">REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai – U.A.E
   ...: 
   ...: RERA ID: 12087
   ...: 
   ...: Specialist Licensed Property Brokers &amp; Consultants
   ...: Residential / Commercial – Buying, Selling, R <a href="http://www.justproperty.com/company_view/index/3963">...Read more...</a></td>""", type="html")

In [3]: selector.xpath("normalize-space(.//td)")
Out[3]: [<Selector xpath='normalize-space(.//td)' data=u'REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai \u2013 U.A.E RERA ID'>]

In [4]: selector.xpath("normalize-space(.//td)").extract()
Out[4]: [u'REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai \u2013 U.A.E RERA ID: 12087 Specialist Licensed Property Brokers & Consultants Residential / Commercial \u2013 Buying, Selling, R ...Read more...']

In [5]: [td.xpath("normalize-space(.)").extract() for td in selector.css("td")]
Out[5]: [[u'REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai \u2013 U.A.E RERA ID: 12087 Specialist Licensed Property Brokers & Consultants Residential / Commercial \u2013 Buying, Selling, R ...Read more...']]

In [7]:
```

Remember `normalize-space()` will consider only the 1st node in the node-set you give as argument, so it usually does what you want if you are sure your argument will match one and only one node you want.

Comment: When the king of scrapy comes, we all ears. Thanks a lot. miss u bty :)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, if you have 1 specific node in mind, you can call `normalize-space()` on it to get all descendant text nodes concatenated. I edited the answer to show how

Comment: help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646323/scrapyd-deploy-is-not-recognized

Comment: Hi @pault. , I see your answers about scrapy a lot. Thanks for those answers. Please could you check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665819/error-when-deploying-scrapy-project-on-the-scrapy-cloud). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, I've asked my colleagues at Scrapinghub

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, I havent followed that discussion. You should ping dangra there

Comment: @pault. who is "dangra" please

Comment: the one you last replied to: @dangra (a.k.a Daniel Grana)

Answer (score 1):

`normalize-space(//td/text())` works for me.

Demo (using xmllint):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "normalize-space(//td/text())"
REGEN REAL ESTATE, Dubai – U.A.E RERA ID: 12087 Specialist Licensed Property Brokers & Consultants Residential / Commercial – Buying, Selling, R
```

Where `input.xml` contains the xml you've provided.

Comment: The thing is `normalize-space(//td/text())` will only take the first node of the `//td/text()` node-set. So you get whitespace normalized string of the first descendant text node of the `td`, so you won't get   "...Read more..."

Comment: @alecxe, far from that :) I only know a few XPath tricks. Still plenty to learn for me. You're quite a star too ;)

Comment: @pault. anyway, thanks so much for helping in `scrapy` tag, questions usually don't receive enough attention in the tag.