# windows scrapyd-deploy is not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd

I have install the scrapyd like this

```
pip install scrapyd
```

I want to use scrapyd-deploy

when i type scrapyd

i got this exception in cmd:

> 'scrapyd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: `scrapyd-deploy` doesn't work? please share console output

Comment: @pault. I told you what cmd gives me, this all what i got

Comment: is this Windows? linux?

Comment: I'm no Windows guy sorry. I asked around

Comment: @pault. is it possible that the scrapyd is not availabe on windows. i discovered that fomr this site http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html becuse there is no windows configurations

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and I also read some opinions that scrapyd isn't available / can't run on windows and nearly gave it up (didn't really need it as I intend on deploying to a linux machine, wanted scrapyd on windows for debug purposes). However, after some research I found a way. As I haven't found any clear instructions on this, I will try to make my answer as detailed as possible, listing all the steps that worked for me.

Assuming you want to run scrapyd on your local machine, you will need two command lines running: The first is used to connect to scrapyd and keeping the connection open, and the second is for deploying and scheduling.

- You already pip installed scrapyd.
- Create a folder C:\scrapyd and an empty .log file named scrapyd.log in this folder (not sure this step is necessary).
- Open your cmd and cd to your Scripts folder inside Python. This is usually something like: C:\Python27\Scripts. Type: `python scrapyd`
- At this point you should see something like that:

  ```
  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [-] Log opened.

  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [-] twistd 13.2.0 (C:\Python27\python.exe 2.7.6) starting up.

  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.

  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [-] Site starting on 6800

  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x0000000003F69208>

  2014-03-26 13:57:30+0200 [Launcher] Scrapyd 1.0.1 started: max_proc=16, runner='scrapyd.runner'
  ```
- If you can open your browser and go to `http://localhost:6800` then you're ok. The command line window should stay open in the background as connection will be closed if you'll close it.
- On windows explorer navigate to your scrapy project folder and edit the scrapy.cfg file found there: write your deploy target name: [deploy:scrapyd] for instance, and uncomment the url line.
- Open a second command line and cd to your scrapy project folder. Type: `scrapy deploy -l`
- Deploy: type: `scrapy deploy scrapyd -p project_name` (scrapyd is your target). You should get a server response code 200 and an ok status. You can check if deploy was successful also by typing: `scrapy deploy -L scrapyd`
- Scheduling: you need to install curl for windows. Here's how: [questions/9507353/steps-to-setup-curl-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/steps-to-setup-curl-in-windows) 
  type: `curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=project_name -d spider=spider_name`
  Again, you should get an ok status, and in your browser at `http://localhost:6800` under jobs you can check whether the job was indeed scheduled.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many Thanks. Just one thing please. You wrote `scrapy deploy -1`, It should be `scrapy deploy -l`

Comment: True. That's `scrapy deploy -l`.

Comment: TL;DR: The scrapyd and scrapyd-deploy scripts are found in the Scripts folder of the python installation, and are really just python scripts. One solution is to explicitly call them with the python interpreter.

Comment: In my case, deploy was no longer available.  I was able to get it working after copying the scrapyd-deploy file to my scrapy project folder root and add the `.py` file extension to the file.  Then, from the command line, I was able to call `scrapyd-deploy.py -l`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you install scrapyed-client by using `pip install scrapyd-client` I suggest try this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client
```

it worked for me.

thanks to [scrapyd-client command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750739/scrapyd-client-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

For me proposed solution above didn't work.

Below what worked for me: (for scrapy in version 0.24).

Go to `C:\Python27\Scripts` and create two files:

```
scrapy.bat

scrapyd-deploy.bat
```

Edit both files with notepad and paste:

In the `scrapy.bat` file:

```
@echo off
c:\Python27\python c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy %*
```

In the `scrapyd-deploy.bat` file:

```
@echo off
c:\Python27\python c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapyd-deploy %*
```

Then save these files and restart cmd.

If you have `C:\Python27\Python` and `C:\Python27\Scripts` in your `PATH` then both commands `scrapy` and `scrapyd-deploy` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Marcin Rapacz's answer work for me. However, I use anaconda to manage my
python library. So, the files should be in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts", and content in files should be changed like:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapyd-deploy" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```