# TypeError in scrapyd

Tags: python, scrapyd

I have started `scrapyd` in my cmd, and the website "localhost:8600" shows normally.
Then I began to deploy a project named scrapyd_prac, and changed the content of project's "scrapy.cfg' as:

```
 [deploy:localhost]
    url = http://localhost:6800/
    project = scrapyd_prac
```

Then I execute the command in cmd:

```
python D:\scrapyd_test\Scripts\scrapyd-deploy localhost -p scrapyd_prac
```

and it returns like this:

```
Packing version 1500791181
Deploying to project "scrapyd_prac" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):

{"status": "error", "message": "environment can only contain strings",        "node_name": "YLMF-1609111715"}
```

I am confused, please help me.

Comment: Your question is different, but you may glean some good information from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662909

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same situation on Win10 Python2.7 & Scrapyd 1.2.0 environment.

Then I came across to this bug [scrapyd github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client/issues/49)

Then I uninstalled Scrapyd by pip uninstall scrapdy

Installed an older version, pip install scrapyd==1.1.0

And it worked like a charm.