# scrapyd-client command not found

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I'd just installed the scrapyd-client(1.1.0) in a virtualenv, and run command 'scrapyd-deploy' successfully, but when I run 'scrapyd-client', the terminal said: command not found: scrapyd-client.

According to the readme file(https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client), there should be a 'scrapyd-client' command.

I had checked the path '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd-client', only 'scrapyd-deploy' in the folder.

Is the command 'scrapyd-client' being removed for now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a fresh environment and install scrapyd-client first using below

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client
```

And it should work. I was able to get it

```
$ which scrapyd-client
/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/sclient/bin/scrapyd-client
```

The package on pip may not be the latest one

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani when I run your command `scrapyd-client` installs, but when I try to run `scrapyd-client projects` for example - I get error `simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. And every command goes with that error. what that could be?

Comment: @Chiefir, that would be a different issue, please open a new Question and share the link here if you want