# Error when deploying scrapy project on the scrapy cloud

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using scrapy 0.20 on Python 2.7.

I want to deploy my scrapy project on [scrapy cloud](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud)

1. I developed my scrapy project with simple spider.
2. navigate to my scrapy project folder.
3. typed `scrapy deploy scrapyd -d koooraspider` on cmd. Where `koooraspider` is my project's name, and `scrapyd` is my target.

I got the following error:

```
D:\Walid-Project\Tasks\koooraspider>scrapy deploy scrapyd -p koooraspider
Packing version 1395847344
Deploying to project "koooraspider" in http://dash.scrapinghub.com/api/scrapyd/a
ddversion.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 168, in <module>
    execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py"
, line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\de
ploy.py", line 105, in run
    if not _upload_egg(target, egg, project, version):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\de
ploy.py", line 194, in _upload_egg
    return _http_post(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\commands\de
ploy.py", line 210, in _http_post
    f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1173, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1142, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 987, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 801, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 373: ordina
l not in range(128)
```

#### scrapy.cfg

```
# Project: KoooraSpider
[deploy:scrapyd]
url = http://dash.scrapinghub.com/api/scrapyd/
username = MyUserName
password =
project = 2431
```

#### Note

When I did the previous steps, `project.egg-info` folder, `build` folder, and `setup.py` script have been generated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the scrapy.cfg generated by https://dash.scrapinghub.com/p/2431/deploy/ ?

Comment: what version of w3lib are you using? is it possible to upgrade Scrapy to 0.22.2 (latest stable) too?

Comment: @dangra I need to work with scrapy 0.20. Also how to to the version of v3lib plesae?

Answer (score 1):

remove `project.egg-info` & `build` folders

and then try command `scrapy deploy scrapyd -p 2431`

Comment: The two folders have been generated again, and I received the exactly same error message.